# Как работать с массивами в PHP или фильтр слов

Tags: php

Нужно сделать фильтр запросов, есть переменная `$request`, которая содержит запрос от посетителя, есть вторая переменая `$bad_word`, которая хранит список запрещенных слов в файле в формате `bad_word' => "Секс, порно, и тд"` для разделения слов используется запятая и пробел. 
Нужно сделать так, что бы при совпадении любого слова из переменной `$bad_word` переменная `$request` принимала пустое значение.
 Желательно, чтобы слова из `bad_word` можно было использовать независимо от регистра.
 Сам я в PHP слабо разбираюсь, можно сказать начинающий, а сделать это нужно сейчас. 
Спасибо, буду благодарен за любые подсказки.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы получить из строки *$bad_word* массив слов воспользуйтесь функцией *[explode()](http://php.su/functions/?explode)*, для перебора и проверки всех элементов массива подойдет цикл *[foreach](http://php.su/learnphp/cs/?cycles#foreach)*, для поиска слов в предложении можно использовать *[stripos()](http://php.su/functions/?stripos)*.

Comment: Спасибо,почитал, много интересного,но вот как это реализовать на практике? Не от лени своей спрашиваю, просто я не программист, немного понимаю HTML, но дальше для меня "темный лес". Думаю для знающего человека это займет 5 минут, а я сегодня весь день на это потратил..

Comment: Если Вы не программист и не планируете им стать, проще всего сэкономить время обратившись на <a href="http://www.free-lance.ru/">free-lance.ru</a>. И Вам, за деньги, напишут готовый скрипт любой сложности.

Comment: Скрипт работает, я всего лишь хочу доработать его, ведь даже я не программист понимаю что тут всего 3-6 строк кода, я могу оплатить в пределах разумного, если бесплатно ни кто помочь не может.
 ICQ 305 405 000 или admydoor_собака_yandex.ru

Answer (score -1):

Вам нужно просто найти вхождение подстроки в строку. Используйте [mb_stripos()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-stripos.php), которая в отличии от [stripos()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stripos.php) работает с UTF-8 символами.

```
<?php
$needle = trim($request);
if(mb_stripos($bad_word, $needle) !== false){
    $request = null;
}
?>
```

Comment: было бы не плохо увидеть мнения минусующих